# Unable to apply Windows Updates as domain administrator

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

I cannot install Windows Updates on any server while logged in as the domain administrator.

[image: Windows Update cannot currently check for updates]

The domain controller was recently migrated from a Server 2003 machine to a Server 2008 machine. This included an old administrator account with a different username. This user account can install updates.

I'd like to get rid of the old administrator account and continue on with the new one, however I can't see the differences between these two accounts that would effect installing Windows Updates (e.g. group memberships).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't look like a problem with the account that you're using. It sounds like you have a Computer GPO configured to restrict Windows Update. You can verify this by running `gpresult /H` and viewing the output. It should be obvious where the offending GPO is.

---

If this really is a group membership problem, you can view detailed group information for each account by logging in and running `whoami /groups`.

Comment: Thanks! It was a GPO - User Configuration/Windows Components/Windows Update.