# Adding a new local user hangs netplwiz on server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-accounts

I'm logged into a Windows Server 2008 R2 box as a domain admin. I'm trying to explicitly make myself local admin. From netplwiz, I choose add user, administrator, and click OK. Netplwiz becomes unresponsive and has to be killed. I try again: choose standard user, click Finish -- same result.

EDIT: Here's what was in Event Viewer:

> The program NetplWiz.exe version 6.1.7600.16385 stopped interacting
>   with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the
>   problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center
>   control panel.

I've never seen this before. Any ideas?

Comment: anything in event log?

Comment: Nothing useful -- added it to the question above.

Comment: can you add yourself explicitly via Server Manager -> Configuration -> Local Users and Groups -> Groups ?

Comment: "The computer...is a domain controller. This snap-in cannot be used on a domain controller. Domain accounts are managed with the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in." Maybe that's the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments you are trying to do this on a domain controller. DC's don't have any local users or groups, they are removed as part of the promotion process. This would be why it's hanging since it can't actually do the function that it is trying to do.